# What is this plant with rosette leaf arrangement that grew beside my palm?

Tags: identification, palm, volunteer

What is the name of this plant with small leaves? Is it bad for my palm? Should I keep it or remove it? Or can I replant it into another pot?

[image: my palm]

Comment: Leave it for now! Won't hurt your palm for a while.  Have you fertilized your palm lately?  At all?  Do you have a bird near this plant?  Is this indoors or out of doors?  Does the palm get moved sometimes?  What happened a month ago?  Is this soil potting soil or is it garden soil?  Fun little mystery.  Let's figure out what it is first, then if it is cool we'll help you to repot it or if not wanted how to rip  it out and put it in the compost bin.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I've used a fertilizer about a month ago. No, I don't have a bird. It's indoors. Yes, I leave it beside the kitchen window during the day and bring it to my room in the evening. I'm not sure what soil is this because I'm new to plants and bought it from flower shop about two months ago. Thank you for your advice. I'll leave it and see what will happen. :-)

Comment: As a side note, I think your palm is not a real palm but _Cycas revoluta_. Some call it a Sago palm, but it is not a real palm.

Comment: Do the leaves smell on touching?

Comment: Wondering where the seed came from to be planted in your pot.  Plants do well together to a certain extent.  I rarely have just one plant in a pot.  As long as one is on top of the chemistry.  What kind of fertilizer?  A month ago?  Kind of sounds as if that was when a seed could have been added to your pot, huh?

Comment: @b.nota  Glad you brought that up...I agree.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recognise it currently, but if there's any chance it's something you might want to keep, extract it carefully now, keeping the roots as intact as possible without damaging the roots of the palm, and pot it up separately. All the time its growing there, its stealing a tiny amount of  nutrients and water from the palm, but worse, the roots are getting larger and intertwining with the palm roots - if its something you want, you won't be able to extract it successfully later, and if its something you don't want, it'll be difficult to get all the roots out so it doesn't  grow again.

The likelihood is, it's something you don't want, but either way, it needs to come out of that pot now.